# How can I help Adsense verify my traffic?

Tags: google-adsense

It the past two months ads display kept going on and off (mostly off) for reason they "can"t verify the value of the traffic".
My traffic is 100% real, all coming from Google Play (my webpages show in my apps) and I get about 8K entries per day.
Sadly AdMob ia currently not an option for UX reasons (Banners) and development incompabilities (Intrrsititials)
I'm about to give up...
How can I help Adsense verfiy my traffic or talk to a support agent there?

Comment: If the pages are embedded in apps, are you using appropriate placements for apps as opposed to for web pages? https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722057?hl=en

Comment: Hi Stephen. Yes I'm 100% using appropriate placements for apps.